# IntelliJ Tomcat hot swap resources to avoid server restart

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a webapp which I deploy to local Tomcat server. When I change e.g. some css, I need to restart server to see the changes in the webapp. Is it possible somehow to hot swap resources (css,js) to be able to see changes after page refresh in browser?

It is annoying to always restart the Tomcat to see the changes.

IntelliJ v2020.2

Tomcat v8

Comment: You may configure "On update" actions: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html

Comment: Your link could be helpful, thank you.